# Accessing Complex Types through properties in a Knockout,js foreach binding

Tags: knockout.js

I am having trouble understanding how I should go about using the property of a property of an item of a given array.

Below is an example of the JSON response I get:

```
[{
"Id":"3bddaa55-5cae-4d9d-8c2f-3cff9a853aa0",
"ServiceRequestId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"AuthorizationRequestId":"48c73685-ee1e-4eea-8bf0-74320d37c80c",
"Quantity":0,
"TreatmentStartDate":null,
"Dosage":{"Id":"cbdbed9e-4c80-4f5a-8a4b-8185c24e45a0",
          "Value":13.4,
          "Unit":"Spiel mit mehr"},
"Medication":{"IsAutoApproveWhiteList":null,
              "IsPartB":null,"Id":"b0f0e31c-3467-4d73-9dd5-e806a20223a3",
              "Name":"Pills of Awesomeness",
              "Code":"J1100",
              "BrandName":"Awesome Pills",
              "GenericName":"Awesome",
              "UnitOfMeasure":"Pounds",
"Dosages":[{"Id":"dd6e7cfb-252c-46c1-815f-832f9501e9ce",
            "Value":100,
            "Unit":"Fart"},
            {"Id":"4dc88918-c359-41fd-9eb8-50699ba627fd",
             "Value":75.6,
             "Unit":"Ride wit me."}],
            "MedicationType":725060001,
            "AllowedDiagnoses":null},
"DirectionsForUse":{"Id":"9faba6ed-5a67-4b45-bedb-a49191274cc7",
                    "Name":"Do not eat sand",
                    "IsValidAsLoadingDose":false},
"Refills":0,
"RequiredRegimenMedicationId":null,
"OptionalRegimenMedicationId":null,
"NonRegimenMedicationId":null,
"RequiredRegimenMedicationDosingId":null,
"OptionalRegimenMedicationDosingId":null,
"NonRegimenMedicationDosingId":null,
"DoseType":725060000,
"TypeOfMedication":0,
"MedicationType":0,
"Bsa":null,
"MaximumDosage":null,
"MaximumDosageFormulaId":null,
"NotAutoApprovedReason":0}]
```

Next is the code that I am trying to set up:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Dose</th>
            <th>Directions For Use</th>
            <th>Treatment Start Date</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Refills</th>
            <th>Purchase Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ServiceItems">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $root.Medication.DisplayName"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind=""></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind=""></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind=""></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Quantity"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Refills"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind=""></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>




@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function ServiceItem(data) {
            var self = this;

            self.TreatmentStartDate = ko.observable(data.TreatmentStartDate);
            self.ServiceRequestId = data.ServiceRequestId;
            self.DoseType = ko.observable(data.DoseType);
            self.Medication = ko.observable(data.Medication);
            self.Dosage = ko.observable(data.Dosage);
            self.DirectionForUse = ko.observable(data.DirectionForUse);
            self.RequiredRegimenMedicationId = ko.observable(data.RequiredRegimenMedicationId);
            self.RequiredRegimenMedicationDosingId = ko.observable(data.RequiredRegimenMedicationDosingId);
            self.OptionalRegimenMedicationId = ko.observable(data.OptionalRegimenMedicationId);
            self.OptionalRegimenMedicationDosingId = ko.observable(data.OptionalRegimenMedicationDosingId);
            self.NonRegimenMedicationId = ko.observable(data.NonRegimenMedicationId);
            self.NonRegimenMedicationDosingId = ko.observable(data.NonRegimenMedicationDosingId);
            self.Quantity = ko.observable(data.Quantity);
            self.Refills = ko.observable(data.Refills);
        }

        function Medication(data) {
            var self = this;

            self.Name = data.Name;
            self.Code = data.Code;
            self.BrandName = data.BrandName;
            self.GenericName = data.GenericName;
            self.UnitOrMeasure = data.UnitOrMeasure;
            self.Dosages = data.Dosages;
            self.MedicationTypes = data.MedicationTypes;
            self.AllowedDiagnoses = data.AllowedDiagnoses;

            self.DisplayName = ko.computed(function () {
                if (self.Name != null && self.Name != "") {
                    return self.Name;
                } else {
                    return self.BrandName;
                }
            });
        }

        function Dosage(data) {
            var self = this;

            self.Id = data.Id;
            self.Value = data.Value;
            self.unit = data.Unit;
        }

        function DirectionForUse(data) {
            var self = this;

            self.Id = data.Id;
            self.Name = data.Name;
            self.IsValidAsLoadingDose = data.IsValidAsLoadingDose;
        }

        function ServiceItemsViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            self.ServiceItems = ko.observableArray();

            //Operations
            self.add = function(item) {
                self.ServiceItems.add(item);
            };

            self.remove = function(item) {
                self.ServiceItems.remove(item);
            };
        }

        var viewModel = new ServiceItemsViewModel();

        $.getJSON('/Mapping/GetServiceItems', function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModel.ServiceItems);
        });

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    </script>
}
```

What I would like is in the first column to have the Medication computed method fire during the foreach binding run.  the line that I am not calling properly is:

```
<td><span data-bind="text: $root.Medication.DisplayName"></span></td>
```

The error message I am getting in my FireBugs Console is:

> Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: TypeError: $root.Medication is undefined;
>   Bindings value: text: $root.Medication.DisplayName

How do I propagate to the Medication property and trigger that method properly?

Thanks!

### EDIT:

```
<td><span data-bind="text: $root.Medication.DisplayName"></span></td>
```

change to:

```
<td data-bind="text: Medication.DisplayName"></td>
```

I also added an alert inside of the function and it does not trigger.

```
function Medication(data) {
        var self = this;

        self.Name = data.Name;
        self.Code = data.Code;
        self.BrandName = data.BrandName;
        self.GenericName = data.GenericName;
        self.UnitOrMeasure = data.UnitOrMeasure;
        self.Dosages = data.Dosages;
        self.MedicationTypes = data.MedicationTypes;
        self.AllowedDiagnoses = data.AllowedDiagnoses;

        self.DisplayName = ko.computed(function () {
            alert('Explode Please');
            if (self.Name != null && self.Name != "") {
                return self.Name;
            } else {
                return self.BrandName;
            }
        });
    }
```

The current result produces no errors and this table result:

[image: Result of above EDIT changes]

Comment: @teresko I'm curious why you changed the 'mvc' tag to the 'asp.net-mvc' tag? This doesn't have anything to do with that stack. If you're going to replace 'mvc' with anything, I'd use 'mvvm'

Comment: @Thr33Dii : the topic has nothing to do with MVC design pattern either, but the code examples indicate use or razor template engine with asp.net mvc framework.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but the primary issue is that in you're setting `Medication`, you are not using the `function Medication(data)` constructor. That is why the computed never fires.

Comment: Weird I made the changes so they are the same as your jsfiddle page and it still is blank for me. :( Still looking into it. You have the right answer I believe but I need to see why mine is not doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

`$root` changes the context of the `foreach` binding to the page viewmodel: `ServiceItemsViewModel`. By default, the context inside the `foreach` is `ServiceItem`. Because `ServiceItem` is the context and it's the viewmodel that contains `Medication`, the correct binding for the `span` is: `<span data-bind="text: Medication.DisplayName"></span>`

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

You will also want to fix this line:
`self.Medication = ko.observable(data.Medication);`
Should be: `self.Medication = ko.observable(new Medication(data.Medication));`

I'm doubtful that it even needs to be an observable, but I can't be certain without knowing the rest of the behavior of the page.

**Binding Suggestion**
I would bind to the `<td>` directly like this:
`<td data-bind="text: Medication.DisplayName"/>`

http://jsfiddle.net/5emCS/1/

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I figured out my own issue. I was dropping to far back down my chain of items using $root.  Thanks

Comment: can you please post the solution ?

Comment: i guess it was $data.Medication.DisplayName

Comment: @ebramtharwat 'Medication' is a child property of 'ServiceItem'. The context of the 'foreach' binding is 'ServiceItem'. Using '$root' changes the context of the span binding to the page viewmodel, whatever that may be. The page viewmodel does not have the 'Medication' property. The correct binding is simply: 'Medication.DisplayName'

Comment: Although I not longer get the error removing the $root and bringing it down to Medication.DisplayName it is coming up black if I try to debug with firebug it never triggers. So I am investigating a bit more. Might have a complete answer soon.